# ActiveMQ : How to force failover on Broker side?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have 2 Brokers and in specific scenario i want to force the client to connect the a specific broker.

How can I achieve it without dropping the other Broker while using the Failover mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [priority backup feature](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) of the failover URI to indicate a preference for a specific broker which it try and stay connected to, if that broker goes down it will fail to any other broker that you have configured and keep trying to reconnect to the priority backup in the background.

Comment: Probably I was not clear, I have 2 identical servers. In some cases I want to block one of the Brokers (Can be any of them) and then the Failover will cause the client to connect to the other Broker automatically.

Comment: Seems you don't even fully have an idea of what you want to do, perhaps reformulate your question to clarify in your mind what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement, frequently. For clarity, I use failover with two brokers A and B, A is currently the primary and I have an issue requiring a restart. I want to cause all sending clients to connect to B while I leave the consumers to empty the queues on A, when the queues are empty I restart A.

The only way I've found to do this is to close the activeMQ port on A then my sending clients connect to B and my consumer on A (running on the same machine fortunately) can empty the queues. As well as closing the port it seemed I had to also execute 
    iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport  -j REJECT

YMMV

Comment: Hello, I'm actually having the exact opposite problem, where I tried to create an automatic failover environment, but it somehow never works when I dropped or rejected the port. It seemed that somehow it doesn't want to switch over to the slave machine after I dropped or rejected the port, it just warns me with a FailoverTransport. Is it possible for you to post your server-side and broker-side configurations? Thanks!